# Interesting mathematical topics to discuss in the essay

Tags: article-writing

I need to write an essay about some interesting math problem. Does anyone have any idea which problem, theorem, questions I can use? 
I thought about discussing "The history of number zero" or "Euclidean vector", something like that.
Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Note that the essay should be about something interesting for you, instead of interesting for somebody else. I think you should say what are you interested about. Furthermore, saying what is your level of knowledge is relevant. See also more info on [homework questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: Analytic and Algebraic Topology of Locally Euclidean Metrization
of Infinitely Differentiable Riemannian Manifold.

Comment: I'm personally a bit biased towards logic and set theory, so how about Cantor's work on infinity in set theory or Godel's proof.

Comment: I am an undergraduate student studying mathematics and informatics. I honestly find every area interesting. Your ideas are really helpful. Thank you so much for your answers.